# Find the most combinations of two numbers that equal third or get close to it

Tags: java, performance, programming-challenge

My task is to find how many different "tasks" can be done if I have two types of tasks that take specific time and time to complete all of them. I have to find the most tasks that can be done so that the gap between the time and sum of tasks is minimal. For example consider this input:

```
3 5 55
```

And output(2x5 + 15x3):

```
17
```

Or:

```
Input: 886 340 6177, Output: 10
```

Also:

```
Input: 3 5 54, Output: 18
```

My code is this:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Protsessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = in.nextInt(); //Time of first task
        int n = in.nextInt(); //Time of second task
        int t = in.nextInt(); //Time available

        int tmpgap;
        int gap = t;
        int tasks = 0;
        int t1  = t;

        if( m <= 0|| n <= 0) { //If input is 0 or less
            System.out.println(0);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(m > n) { //I rearrange my input as it doesn't work when m is bigger then n
            int tmp = m;
            m = n;
            n = tmp;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (t/m+1); i++) {
            int tmptasks = 0;
            t1 -= i*m;
            tmptasks += i;
            for (int j = 0; j < (t/n+1) && t1 >= n; j++) {
                t1 -= n;
                tmptasks++;
            }
            tmpgap = t1;
            if(tmpgap <= gap){
                gap = tmpgap;
                tasks = tmptasks;
            }
            t1 = t;

        }
        System.out.println(tasks);
    }
}
```

As my code is quite messy, how can I optimize/improve it using dynamic programming?

NOTE: This was a task in competetive programming lesson, I already submitted this code(passed).

Answer (score 1):

Have you simply tried to split code into smaller functions?

```
int t = in.nextInt(); //Time available
```

How about simply naming it `timeAvailable` instead of `t` ?

```
if(m > n) { //I rearrange my input as it doesn't work when m is bigger then n
    int tmp = m;
    m = n;
    n = tmp;
}
```

Common pattern is something like:

```
int calculate(int m, int n, int t) {
    if (m > n) {
        return calculate(n, m, t);
    }
    ...
}
```

Try to declare variables in smallest possible scope - `int tmpgap;` should be inside the for-loop. The inner for-loop might be replaced by division + Math.floor().

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Now are there ways I could also optimize the perfomance of my code?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  public class Protsessor {
> ```

Is that a typo for `Processor`? Either way, it doesn't seem to communicate much about what the class does.

---

> ```
>         if( m <= 0|| n <= 0) { //If input is 0 or less
>             System.out.println(0);
>             System.exit(0);
>         }
> ```

Good to see that you've thought about corner cases. It's debatable whether `System.exit(0)` is better here or `return` (since you're in `main`).

---

> ```
>         int tmpgap;
>         int gap = t;
>         int tasks = 0;
>         int t1  = t;
>         ...
>         for (int i = 0; i < (t/m+1); i++) {
>             int tmptasks = 0;
>             t1 -= i*m;
>             tmptasks += i;
>             for (int j = 0; j < (t/n+1) && t1 >= n; j++) {
>                 t1 -= n;
>                 tmptasks++;
>             }
>             tmpgap = t1;
>             if(tmpgap <= gap){
>                 gap = tmpgap;
>                 tasks = tmptasks;
>             }
>             t1 = t;
>         }
> ```

This is unnecessarily complicated, partly because of the scope issues mentioned already by user158037, but also because it doesn't take full advantage of the ability to initialise a variable, or of the available operators.

> ```
>         for (int i = 0; i < (t/m+1); i++) {
> ```

I don't see any reason not to write

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= t/m; i++) {
```

and similarly in the other loop.

> ```
>             int tmptasks = 0;
>             ...
>             tmptasks += i;
> ```

could just be

```
            int tmptasks = i;
```

> ```
>         int t1  = t;
>         ...
>         for (...) {
>             ...
>             t1 -= i*m;
>             ...
>             t1 = t;
>         }
> ```

could just be

```
        ...
        for (...) {
            ...
            int t1 = t - i*m;
            ...
        }
```

`tmpgap` is just an alias for `t1` where it is defined. Neither is a great name IMO, but I'll give `tmpgap` the edge for consistency with `tmptasks`.

Applying these changes and some tweaks to whitespace for consistency we get

```
        int gap = t;
        int tasks = 0;
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i <= t/m; i++) {
            int tmptasks = i;
            int tmpgap = t - i*m;
            for (int j = 0; j <= t/n && tmpgap >= n; j++) {
                tmpgap -= n;
                tmptasks++;
            }
            if (tmpgap <= gap) {
                gap = tmpgap;
                tasks = tmptasks;
            }
        }
```

Now we can look more closely at that inner loop. Suppose we want to extract an upper bound `J` such that we can rewrite it as

```
            for (int j = 0; j < J; j++) {
                tmpgap -= n;
                tmptasks++;
            }
```

Can we do that? `J` is just the number of times we do the second task, so it's quite easy: `J = tmpgap / n;`. But if we now have

```
            int J = tmpgap / n;
            for (int j = 0; j < J; j++) {
                tmpgap -= n;
                tmptasks++;
            }
```

we can optimise away the loop:

```
            int J = tmpgap / n;
            tmpgap -= J * n;
            tmptasks += J;
```

Inlining `J` and reordering,

```
            tmptasks += tmpgap / n;
            tmpgap -= (tmpgap / n) * n;
```

But (at least when all the values are positive), that last line is equivalent to

```
            tmpgap %= n;
```

So we're down to

```
        int gap = t;
        int tasks = 0;
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i <= t/m; i++) {
            int tmptasks = i;
            int tmpgap = t - i*m;
            tmptasks += tmpgap / n;
            tmpgap %= n;
            if (tmpgap <= gap) {
                gap = tmpgap;
                tasks = tmptasks;
            }
        }
```

and we can continue reordering and inlining (and maybe bring back `t1` for some clarity) to get

```
        int gap = t;
        int tasks = 0;
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i <= t/m; i++) {
            int t1 = t - i*m;
            int tmptasks = i + t1 / n;
            int tmpgap = t1 % n;
            if (tmpgap <= gap) {
                gap = tmpgap;
                tasks = tmptasks;
            }
        }
```

There's still more optimisation to be done! Consider a variant on one of your examples: `3 5 55`. Is it really necessary to loop through `55 / 3 + 1 = 19` cases? No! We have (inlining for clarity) `tmpgap = (t - i*m) % n`. So increasing `i` by one causes it to follow a sequence of values modulo `n`: in this case,

```
m    (55-3m)%5
0    0
1    2
2    4
3    1
4    3
5    0
6    2
...
```

In this case it loops through all `n` possibilities: for other inputs it will loop through fewer than `n` possibilities. But it's never necessary to loop through more than `n`.

To handle the tie-breaker `i` needs to be descending so that the first time we hit the optimum `tmpgap` we also have the optimum `tmptasks`; to detect the cycle we need an extra variable outside the loop or a repeated calculation inside it. E.g.

```
        int gap = t;
        int tasks = 0;
        ...
        for (int i = t/m; i >= 0; i--) {
            int t1 = t - i*m;
            int tmptasks = i + t1 / n;
            int tmpgap = t1 % n;

            if (i < t/m && tmpgap == t % m % n) {
                break;
            }

            if (tmpgap <= gap) {
                gap = tmpgap;
                tasks = tmptasks;
            }
        }
```

With a bit more work you can pre-calculate when the `break` will be hit, but this post is already too long, so I'm not going to elaborate it any more.